# Multiple widget sizes and one WidgetProvider

Tags: android

I have in my application a widget with 3 different sizes So I have 3 AppWidgetProvider Java classes.
Is there any way to write a single AppWidgetProvider  java class and detect which size widget the user has clicked.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can do this. In the AndroidManifest.xml you can give only one resource to the AppWidgetProvider receiver.

Comment: that's ok, then how can I distinguish the size when control reaches the receiver

Comment: you can get the `minWidth` and `minHeight` from `AppWidgetProviderInfo`, and by the way use `AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(int appWidgetId)` to retrieve the `AppWidgetProviderInfo`